# Json stringify the array of object so that i can parse line by line in perl side

Tags: javascript, json, perl

I have the following code :

```
var obj = [];
var myObj1 = {"abc":"aaa","xyz":"bbb"};
obj.push(myobj1);
var myobj2 = {"abc":"vvv","xyz":"ccc"};
obj.push(myobj2);
```

//send `JSON.stringify(obj)` into perl
Now in perl , if i do :
//open the json file and read

```
while(<FILE>){
  my @array = decode_json($_);
}
```

I am getting whole file as one line. How to decode line by line ??

Comment: Stringify returns a string without any newlines.

Comment: ok... But if i do stringify objects myobj1 and myobj2 instead of outer obj then ??

Comment: Why do you want to parse it line by line? Is it because you have memory problems?

Answer (score 0):

obj.push("\n");
[{"abc":"aaa","xyz":"bbb"},"\n", {"abc":"vvv","xyz":"ccc"},"\n"]" 
and then you can detect "\n" line by line.